# Reprint rows multiple times with modifications

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize in advance for my beginner-ness, but I have a few rows I want to reprint 12 times on another location in the document with the sum divided by 12.

I want this:

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

```
Sub computeThis()
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:D3")

For Each row In rng.Rows 'Throws no error but doesn't seem to loop twice either'
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'Set the starting cell number'
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 2
    
    'Repeat 12 times..'
    For i = 1 To 12
        '..with new values'
        Cells(x, 6).Value = Range("A2").Value 'Needs to update with each loop'
        Cells(x, 7).Value = i 'Works OK'
        Cells(x, 8).Value = Range("C2").Value 'Needs to update with each loop'
        Cells(x, 9).Value = Range("D2").Value / 12 'Needs to update with each loop'
        
        x = x + 1
    Next i
Next row
End Sub
```

Problems are as follows:

- It only runs 12 times, so it seems only the For-loop runs
- The A-column, the Account-column that is, needs to change dynamically based on whats in the next row
- The C-column, the Kst-column that is, needs to change dynamically aswell
- The Sum-column aswell, since the values there also changes

I realise the question is kinda stupid, but I'd love some pointers on these problems because I'm not really moving forward here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `X` is getting reset to 2 at the beginning of the outer loop, so it looks like it is running once but it's actually overwriting your first loop.

I added a new variable to increment the row number. I also changed your types from Integer to Long, don't use Integer type in VBA it can cause overflow errors.

```
Sub computeThis()
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:D3")
Dim x As Long
x = 2
Dim j As Long
j = 2
For Each row In rng.Rows 'Throws no error but doesn't seem to loop twice either'
    
    Dim i As Long

    
    'Repeat 12 times..'
    For i = 1 To 12
        '..with new values'
        Cells(j, 6).Value = Range("A" & x).Value 'Needs to update with each loop'
        Cells(j, 7).Value = i 'Works OK'
        Cells(j, 8).Value = Range("C" & x).Value 'Needs to update with each loop'
        Cells(j, 9).Value = Range("D" & x).Value / 12 'Needs to update with each loop'
        j = j + 1

    Next i
    x = x + 1
Next row
End Sub
```